# How can Build.VERSION_CODES possibly work?

Tags: java, android

I'm confused on the internal workings of the Android API's.


If my app is compiled against Android 5.0, then it's acceptable that the following works on a device running Android 5.0 and up:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
```

However, this still works if I run it on a device running older versions of Android. My assumption is that the library on that device doesn't have a definition for the variable `Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP`. Then how can the variable be resolved on those older devices when the app runs this code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Then how can the variable be resolved on those older devices when the app runs this code?

Simple: there is no variable.

`Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP` is a `static final int`. The **`javac`**-generated bytecodes will inline the `int` value when you reference 
`Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP`, rather than doing the lookup for that value at runtime. Since the bytecodes contain the `int`, your APK contains the `int`, and therefore you are not dependent upon the device's edition of the framework to supply the `int` to you.

`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` is *not* a `static final int`, and therefore *that* value is looked up at runtime.

Comment: Amendment: `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` is a [`static final int`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.L_preview/android/os/Build.java#139). But its value depends on a [system property](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.L_preview/android/os/Build.java#503) so it has to be computed at runtime, while `Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP` is just an [`int`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.L_preview/android/os/Build.java#503).