# Android app coding error

Tags: java, pocket, reward

I downloaded a source code and i saw some errors i cannot fix on my on its listed below

**MainActivity.java**

package com.droidoxy.pocket;

also got error in import android.transition.*;

```
private void checkReadPhoneStatePermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (!hasGetReadPhoneStatePermission()) {
            requestReadPhoneStatePermission();
        }
    }
}

private boolean hasGetReadPhoneStatePermission() {
    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

private void requestReadPhoneStatePermission() {
    //You can choose a more friendly notice text. And you can choose any view you like, such as dialog.
    Toast.makeText(this, "Only grant the permission, can you start the mission!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
}

//Callback for requestPermission
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    try {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE: {
                    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "The Permission has granted,you can get your mission now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        //had not get the permission
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Not get the permission,so you cannot get your mission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    break;
                }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**values/styles.xml**

@color/colorPrimary
        @color/colorPrimaryDark

```
</style>
```

```
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I was able to solve some of the problem but I can't solve al

Comment: can you delete your answer ;
http://stackoverflow.com/a/41677768/1332870

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from my knowledge  and here [Android version check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623943/android-version-check)

** I changed **

```
private void checkReadPhoneStatePermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (!hasGetReadPhoneStatePermission()) {
            requestReadPhoneStatePermission();
        }
    }
}
```

to

```
private void checkReadPhoneStatePermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (!hasGetReadPhoneStatePermission()) {
            requestReadPhoneStatePermission();
        }
    }
}
```

because **M stand for 23** and **N stands for 24**

others are located here [Get Android API level of phone currently running my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993924/get-android-api-level-of-phone-currently-running-my-application/3995388#3995388)

**And for**

**values/styles.xml**

@color/colorPrimary @color/colorPrimaryDark

```
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

I added **android:** to it to look like

**values/styles.xml**

@color/colorPrimary @color/colorPrimaryDark

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Dont know much but hope I need help

Comment: I need help please

Comment: I need help can't any one help me